# Yii Global widget config for a theme

Tags: yii, widget, themes, config, global

Is it possible with Yii framework to provide a global configuration for widgets based on a theme?

For example, I want to configure `zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs` to use `>` separator for theme1, `/` for theme2 and so on, not matter how much themes a have.

Comment: the best way around that is to have each team declare a Class that extends `zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs` and then override from there. So, you have something like `class Theme1Breadcrumbs extends CBreadcrumbs... $this->separator='>';...` and  `class Theme2Breadcrumbs extends CBreadcrumbs... $this->separator='/';...`

Comment: @ragingprodigy, but going this way I need some place to set up which concrete realization of CBreadcrumbs to use. Or do you mean that I have just to use different classes in different themes?

Comment: Yes, different classes in different themes.....by the way, in how many places do you make use of CBreadcrumbs within a single theme?

Comment: @ragingprodigy, 1 per page type. But CBreadcrumbs configuration is a good example of what I'm asking about :) Thank you for your reply :)